# Need javascript to solve xyz for a kepler

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements, python, javascript

I have a python program that I use to calculate the xyz positions of a point in a kepler orbit.

https://github.com/sczesla/PyAstronomy/blob/master/src/pyasl/asl/keplerOrbit.py

It takes the following values to define the orbit.

- semi-major axis
- orbit period
- eccentricity
- longitude of the ascending node
- inclination
- longitude of the pericenter

I can then get a position by supplying a time value.

The solution to my problem would be A javascript function that takes the same values as the python one above, and if given a time returns an xyz.

I have not been able to find such a script - if one exists that could be pointed out to me that would solve my problem.

There is one that comes close:

https://github.com/lizard-isana/orb.js/blob/master/src/kepler.js

but this takes different values to calculate the orbit:

- GM
- semi_major_axis
- eccentricity
- inclination
- longitude_of_ascending_node
- argument_of_periapsis
- time_of_periapsis

It will then give an xyz position if supplied with a time.

However I only have the values that I give to the python script above.

I can see how it might be possible, with minor modifications, that orb.js might be tweaked to perform as keplerOrbit.py but I am neither a javascript programmer or a mathematician.

Any help really appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarity "longitude of the pericenter"? The term does not appear in your code.

Comment: "longitude of the pericenter" is Argument of periapsis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that you already have the orbital period, you can use the mean anomaly directly to calculate the `time` parameter. This should work if you set `time_of_periapsis` to `0`, as you have all the other required parameters. (`GM` is `1` since your python program assumes a unit mass system)

Combine everything to a wrapper function, containing nothing but parameter translation and a call to the kepler.js function (kepler.js already has a method of calculating mean anomaly, so you don't need to port any code)

```
//somewhat pseudocode-ish, as it depends on how you actually want to supply the parameters
function keplerOrbitPy_xyz(/*keplerOrbitPy parameters*/){
  let GM = 1;
  let semi_major_axis = keplerOrbitPy.semi_major_axis;
  let eccentricity = keplerOrbitPy.eccentricity;
  let inclination = keplerOrbitPy.inclination;
  let longitude_of_ascending_node = keplerOrbitPy.longitude_of_ascending_node;
  let argument_of_periapsis = keplerOrbitPy.argument_of_periapsis;
  let time_of_periapsis = 0;
  let time = keplerOrbitPy.orbital_period * /*(kepler.js mean anomaly calculation here)*/ / (2*Math.PI);
  return //call to kepler.js xyz here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This perfectly gave me what I need. I am in the process of refining my code but from my initial dirty hack the figures are good -  already I understand how to do so because of your clarity.